# Difference between "full-size" absolute positioning methods

Tags: html, css

When making an absolutely positioned element the full size of its parent, ss there any difference between:

```
.full-size {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and:

```
.full-size {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

I tended to use the top variant but generally when I see it done I see the bottom one used.  I wondered if there was any difference in older browsers or certain scenarios where the two would act in any way different from each other; i.e. whether one was more resilient than the other.

Comment: The `width: 100%` is superfluous in the bottom variant.

Comment: Left that in when copying / pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top variant (setting `width` and `height` to 100%) will not work correctly if the absolutely positioned element has padding or borders, unless you also set `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

The bottom variant (zeroing out the offsets on all sides) will not work with replaced elements such as `img` and `iframe` if they have intrinsic dimensions.

For example, the following image has an intrinsic size of 100 pixels by 100 pixels:

```
<img class="full-size" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
```

By default, this image will always retain its intrinsic size instead of scaling to fit the containing block, regardless of whether it is smaller or larger than the image. Setting `width` and `height` in CSS will override these intrinsic dimensions, allowing the image to scale.

Comment: Also, zeroing opposite offsets approach also didn't work in IE6, that may be the historic reason of 1st variant usage in many cases.